# Postgresql условный оператор в Insert into

Tags: postgresql, sas

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли в оператор insert into добавить условный оператор?
В SAS имеется следующий код:

```
insert into &mpSasLibname..&mpTargetTable (PERIOD, ...перечисление полей... ,TABLE
    %if "%trim(&mpCalcType)" = "DAILY" %then %do; ,ORG_ID %end;)
```

Переписываю функцию на postgresql. И столкнулся с тем, что не знаю как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Что этот оператор должен сделать, использовать другое значение (тогда вам нужен case) или решить вставлять ли строку (тогда вам нужен insert / select).

Comment: insert into записывает новую запись, ее еще не существует, условие к не существующему как сделать? Если запись существует,  есть update set здесь можно добавить условие.

Comment: В том то и дело, что если условие в if верно, то надо произвести вставку данных в ещё одно поле. Правда что ли делить на insert, if, update..На case dbeaver ругается. Не хочет сохранять функцию с условием в insert'e.

Comment: Но вы можете всегда указываьт все колонки, просто если какая то колонка в каком то случае не нужна, то вставлять в нее null или DEFAULT, так что if вам нужен только на вставляемое значение